# iCarousel same images issue

Tags: iphone, ios

In my carousel view after 7 images next image shows the first image , the other one shows the second image although they are different images. I mean after 7 images they start repeat images. I am sure it is coming different images. My images are buttons. When i click them they show detail view. In detail view they show correct images but in carousel not. Do you have any idea what causes that. Thank you.

Comment: i solved it. It is about numberOfVisibleItems

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the reusingView feature wrongly.

You *can* fix it by increasing numberOfVisibleItems, but that's not actually the right way to do it since it uses up more memory and slows down the carousel.

Paste your carousel:viewForItemAtIndex:reusingView: method into the question and I'll check it for you.